# if variable name in data frame column matches names in a vector rename variable

Tags: r, variables, rename

Given a data frame and a vector

```
set.seed(123)

feature <- sample(LETTERS,30,replace = T)
number<-sample(1:100,30, replace = T)
df<-data.frame(feature,number)

rename<-c("N","V","C","E")
```

I want to scan through `df$feature` and if a letter stored in `rename` matches one in the column `df$feature` I want to rename them to `"other"`.

I am quite sure that this must have been answered somewhere already, I have looked for a quite long time though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `%in%` to find the rows which hold `rename`:

```
df$feature[df$feature %in% rename] <- "other"
```

In case `df$feature` is a `factor` and does not contain `other` in the levels you need to add `other` to the levels before you exchange them with:

```
levels(df$feature) <- unique(c(levels(df$feature), "other"))
```

or you cast it to `character` with:

```
df$feature <- as.character(df$feature)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option using `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(feature = str_replace(feature, paste(rename, collapse = "|"), "other"))
```